# Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC6C187788 (KernelBase.dll) in Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe: 0xE0000001 (parameters: 0xFFFFFFFF8000000A)

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2017

I get this error if I switch on breaking at all exceptions:

[image: Error]

This is debug mode. I can't work out what to do now.

Comment: Why don't you load KernelBase.pdb and look at your stack??? It is probably a harmless exception.

Comment: @lakeweb I don't know how.

Comment: Debug->Windows->Call Stack to see your stack. and there is a button in the symbol server dialog `load`.

Comment: @lakeweb Ironically I can't replicate the exception now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call stack is **the** tool for this sort of stuff. You can look down the stack for what/where in your code the exception was triggered. You should keep the stack window available always while debugging.

It is handy to see what is going on when you set breakpoints also. The source is available for the code on the stack most of the time. Then you can hover to see values of stuff that is not yours but you are using.

Let the symbols server load everything up. It is cheap while debugging and eliminates a lot of guess work.

Comment: Turns out with a bit more investigation that these were my own exceptions being generated and were acceptable. They were exceptions that I created and catch and "improvised" by supplying new default data. So I never displayed anything to the user.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not provide an answer to the question. While providing hints that are generally useful (until you start debugging 64-bit code anyway), it does not address the specific issue. This should neither have been posted nor accepted as the best answer.

Comment: Hi @IInspectable Doesn't his question, _I can't work out what to do now_, seek an answer as to how/where to look? Turns out it was his own exception and he/I would not have known that without looking at the stack. It seems to be what he needed to solve the problem.